# The `create_rectangle` function in Python customtkinter doesn't draw the shape right

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a snake game, that for generating parts of the snakes I need to keep add and remove rectangles to shape the snake's body. But if you run the game, the squares look like this instead of being green and big:
[image: squares look like small white pixels]

Although I'm all positive that it's not a problem with the code, but here are the codes for you:
`Snake-Game.py:`

```
from customtkinter import *
from httpx import head
from Mods.Snake import Snake
from Mods.Apple import Apple
WIDTH = 1080
HEIGHT = 720
SPEED = 70
SPACE_SIZE = 50
BODY_PARTS = 3
SNAKE_COLOR = "#00FF00"
APPLE_COLOR = "#FF0000"
BG_COLOR = "#000000"
SPEED_INCREASE_LEVEL = 5
MAP_INCREASE_LEVEL = 30
current_size = BODY_PARTS
ate = False
upgrade = False
snake_position = [0,0]
score = 0
dir = 'down'
w = 0
def main():
    global w
    w = CTk()
    w.title("Snake Game")
    w.resizable(False, False)
    l = CTkLabel(w, text="Score: {}".format(score), font=("consolas", 40))
    l.pack()
    board = CTkCanvas(w, bg=BG_COLOR, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
    board.pack()
    centerize_window(w)
    Listen_for(w, 'left', 'right', 'down', 'up')
    restart(board, l)
    w.mainloop()
def restart(board: CTkCanvas, l: CTkLabel):
    snake = Snake(board, current_size, SPACE_SIZE, SNAKE_COLOR, snake_position[0])
    apple = Apple(board, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SPACE_SIZE, APPLE_COLOR, snake_position)
    start(w, board, l, snake, apple)
def start(window: CTk, canvas: CTkCanvas, label: CTkLabel, snake: Snake, apple: Apple):
    global ate
    global upgrade
    global score
    global current_size
    global SPEED
    global SPACE_SIZE
    global snake_position
    x, y = snake.coo[Head := 0]
    if dir == 'up': y -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif dir == 'down': y += SPACE_SIZE
    elif dir == 'right': x += SPACE_SIZE
    elif dir == 'left': x -= SPACE_SIZE
    snake.coo.insert(Head, (x, y))
    snake.squares.insert(Head, canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+BODY_PARTS, y+BODY_PARTS, fill=SNAKE_COLOR))
    if x == apple.coo[0] and y == apple.coo[1]:
        ate = True
        upgrade = True
        current_size+=1
        print(current_size)
        score+=1 # Make different apples that if you eat them
        # they either give you additional score or decrease your score
        # plus slowing you down for some seconds or forever
        label.configure(text="Score: {}".format(score))
        canvas.delete('apple')
        apple = Apple(canvas, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SPACE_SIZE, APPLE_COLOR, snake.coo)
    else:
        del snake.coo[-1]
        canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])
        del snake.squares[-1]
    if hasCrashed(snake): Game_Over(canvas)
    else:
        if not current_size%SPEED_INCREASE_LEVEL and ate:
            SPEED-=5
            print("Speed: ", SPEED)
            ate = False
        if not current_size%MAP_INCREASE_LEVEL and upgrade:
            snake_position = snake.coo.copy()
            # SPACE_SIZE-=20
            print("Leveled up!")
            upgrade = False
        window.after(SPEED, start, window, canvas, label, snake, apple)
def change_dir(new_dir: str):
    global dir
    if new_dir == 'left' and dir != 'right': dir = new_dir
    elif new_dir == 'right' and dir != 'left': dir = new_dir
    elif new_dir == 'up' and dir != 'down': dir = new_dir
    elif new_dir == 'down' and dir != 'up': dir = new_dir
def hasCrashed(snake: Snake):
    x, y = snake.coo[Head:=0]
    if (x < 0 or x >= WIDTH) or (y < 0 or y >= HEIGHT): return None
    for part in snake.coo[Head+1:]:
        if x == part[0] and y == part[1]: return True
    return False
def Game_Over(canvas: CTkCanvas):
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width()/2, canvas.winfo_height()/2, font=('consolas', 70), text="GAME OVER", fill='red', tag='gameover')
def centerize_window(window: CTk):
    window.update()
    window_width = window.winfo_width()
    window_height = window.winfo_height()
    screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
    X = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
    Y = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))
    window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{X}+{Y}")
def Listen_for(window: CTk, go_left: str, go_right: str, go_down: str, go_up: str):
    window.bind(f'<{go_left.capitalize()}>', lambda event: change_dir(go_left))
    window.bind(f'<{go_right.capitalize()}>', lambda event: change_dir(go_right))
    window.bind(f'<{go_up.capitalize()}>', lambda event: change_dir(go_up))
    window.bind(f'<{go_down.capitalize()}>', lambda event: change_dir(go_down))
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

`Snake.py`:

```
class Snake:
    def __init__(self,
                 canvas,
                 BODY_SIZE: int,
                 BOARD_SIZE: int,
                 SNAKE_COLOR: str,
                 location: list[int]) -> None:
        self.body_size = BODY_SIZE
        self.coo = []
        self.squares = []
        if location == 0: location = [0,0]
        for i in range(0, BODY_SIZE): self.coo.append(location)
        for x, y in self.coo: self.squares.append(canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+BOARD_SIZE, y+BOARD_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR, tag="snake"))
```

`Apple.py`:

```
import random
class Apple:
    def __init__(self,
                 canvas,
                 BOARD_WIDTH: int,
                 BOARD_HEIGHT: int,
                 SPACE_SIZE: int,
                 APPLE_COLOR: str,
                 SNAKE_POSITION: list[int]) -> None:
        SPACE_SIZE = int(SPACE_SIZE)
        while True:
            X = random.randint(0, int((BOARD_WIDTH/SPACE_SIZE)-1))*SPACE_SIZE
            Y = random.randint(0, int((BOARD_HEIGHT/SPACE_SIZE)-1))*SPACE_SIZE
            self.coo = [X,Y]
            if not self.coo in SNAKE_POSITION: break # Force the apple to not appear on snake's body
        canvas.create_oval(X, Y, X+SPACE_SIZE, Y+SPACE_SIZE, fill=APPLE_COLOR, tag="apple")
```

I also have some other problems which I guess I'll post them in different questions, but for now, how can I fix this???

Comment: I'm **not sure** if the people who are about to solve this problem need to see the code or not, and it wouldn't be efficient to wait until someone responds, when I can just share the code right away **in case if anyone needs to see it**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have use the wrong size (`BODY_PARTS`) on the following line:

```py
def start(window: CTk, canvas: CTkCanvas, label: CTkLabel, snake: Snake, apple: Apple):
    ...
    # BODY_PARTS = 3, SPACE_SIZE (50) should be used instead
    snake.squares.insert(Head, canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+BODY_PARTS, y+BODY_PARTS, fill=SNAKE_COLOR))
    ...
```

I think `SPACE_SIZE` should be used instead of `BODY_PARTS`:

```py
snake.squares.insert(Head, canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+SPACE_SIZE, y+SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR))
```

Comment: It worked! wow man! I went through the code too many times! could u explain why is it working this way? I mean, why should I use the `SPACE_SIZE`?

Comment: @PCGDoris It is the size used when creating instance of `Snake` inside `restart()`.

Comment: Oh yeah! alright then! cause I'd followed a little tutorial on creating this.